# Meteor call scope variable won't be set

Tags: meteor

I'm having quite a bit of trouble with the scope of the Meteor.call procedure. It won't set my scope variable to the result.length

```
'takeaways': function (userId) {
    var len = 0;

    Meteor.call('userTakeaways', userId, function (error, result) {
        if (error) {
            console.log('there was an error finding the number of messages that were takeaways')
        } else {
            len = result.length; // result.length is 2
        }
    });

    console.log(len); // still 0

    return len;
}
```

Please help!

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

len is not a reactive variable. So if the len value changes, it won't update the spacebar value.

So here two approach to solving this problem:
1. using reactive var/session.

```
 //Make sure you have install reactive var package  
    var len = new ReactiveVar(0); 
    Template['name'].helpers({ 
        'takeaways': function (userId) {
            Meteor.call('userTakeaways', userId, function (error, result) {
               if (error) {
                   console.log('there was an error finding the number of messages that were takeaways')
               } else {
                  len.set(result.length); // result.length is 2
               }
           }); 
        console.log(len.get()); // You will get 2 when response come from you method call. 
        return len.get(); 
        } 
     });
```

2. Using 'simple:reactive-method' package

```
 takeaways : function(userId){
      return ReactiveMethod.call('userTakeaways', userId).length;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding in the else statement

> return len = result.length;

as you can see bellow.

```
'takeaways': function (userId) {
    var len = 0;

    Meteor.call('userTakeaways', userId, function (error, result) {
        if (error) {
            console.log('there was an error finding the number of messages that were takeaways')
        } else {
            return len = result.length; // result.length is 2
        }
    });

console.log(len); // still 0

return len;
```

}

Comment: Hey @NVelosa, I just tried it and it appears that you cannot return anything within the call. The helper just doesn't recognise it for some reason, which is why the 'return len' was outside the Meteor.call  :/

Comment: did you add on the ELSE return len = result.length?

I use that often, look at a print of a [similar situation](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/1/view/37ci4v7zohc4byp/Apps/Shutter/Selection_005.png) on a project i'm currently working on

Comment: Hey @NVelosa. Sorry for the delayed reply. Unfortunately that still doesn't work for me, however the post above that uses simple:reactive-method does work. Thank you for your time though! Really appreciate it